# Delegating value arguments to functions that accept ref arguments

Tags: c#, struct, ref

To reduce maintenance in a library I am developing, I am trying to delegate similar functionality to single functions. As an example, say one has a two component vector with Add functions accepting by-ref args and others accepting by-value args. The idea is to simply call the by-ref function within the by-value functions, making it so that only the by-ref function would have to be maintained.

i.e.

```
struct Vector2
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public Vector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public static void Add(ref Vector2 a, ref Vector2 b, out Vector2 result)
    {
        result.X = a.X + b.X;
        result.Y = a.Y + b.Y;
    }
    public static Vector2 Add1(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
    {
        Add(ref a, ref b, out a);
        return a;
    }
    public static Vector2 Add2(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
    {
        a.X += b.X;
        a.Y += b.Y;
        return a;
    }
}
```

The problem is the by-ref overload function isn't inlined, causing what I believe to be slower code(excluding the nops).

Release output with JIT optimizations enabled:

Add1:

```
          Add(ref a, ref b, out a);
0000002b  lea         eax,[ebp+10h] 
0000002e  push        eax 
0000002f  lea         ecx,[ebp+10h] 
00000032  lea         edx,[ebp+8] 
00000035  call        FFEDA508 
0000003a  nop 
          return a;
0000003b  lea         edi,[ebp-44h] 
0000003e  lea         esi,[ebp+10h] 
00000041  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi] 
00000045  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0 
00000049  nop 
0000004a  jmp         0000004C
```

Add2:

```
          a.X += b.X;
0000002b  fld         dword ptr [ebp+8] 
0000002e  fadd        dword ptr [ebp+10h] 
00000031  fstp        dword ptr [ebp+10h] 
          a.Y += b.Y;
00000034  lea         eax,[ebp+8] 
00000037  fld         dword ptr [eax+4] 
0000003a  lea         eax,[ebp+10h] 
0000003d  fadd        dword ptr [eax+4] 
00000040  fstp        dword ptr [eax+4] 
          return a;
00000043  lea         edi,[ebp-44h] 
00000046  lea         esi,[ebp+10h] 
00000049  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi] 
0000004d  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0 
00000051  nop 
00000052  jmp         00000054
```

Is there a way to get the call to Add to be inlined?

Note that the library requires .NET 4.0, meaning that aggressive inlining isn't available.

Comment: For a first-timer at SO (and probably a lot of regular users) that is a very well researched post! Glad to have you here!

Comment: -Patrick Thanks, but I'm actually not a first time user(I've long forgotten my original account details). 
-DMAN Aggressive inlining isn't available in 4.0, which is the current minimum requirement.

Comment: Please mention this requirement in your question to prevent misconceptions. Deleted my flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to bite the bullet and manually inline the code where inlining isn't automatically done and a call instruction would be significant, such as in a function like Add1. Automated unit tests can handle problem detection in this case, so a maintenance nightmare isn't a huge concern.

Thanks for the help people of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling [aggressive inlining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void Add(ref Vector2 a, ref Vector2 b, out Vector2 result)
{
    result.X = a.X + b.X;
    result.Y = a.Y + b.Y;
}
```

It hints the compiler (or JIT'er) to inline that function.

Note: `AggressiveInlining` is new in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Note: `AggressiveInlining` is new in .Net4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild guess and say you are probably a C++ programmer at heart. The `ref` and `out` keywords you use here are completely superfluent. You can delete them and your code will run just fine.

In fact, I don't see any functionality, that a simple version would not offer:

```
public Vector2 Add(Vector2 other)
{
    return new Vector2() { X = this.X + other.X, Y = this.Y + other.Y };
}
```

Even if you want to keep your API static, remove all `ref` and `out` keywords, they are not necessary for your code.

Edit:

I just noticed you are using structs (value types) so what I wrote before is incorrect and I deleted my post. Then I thought about it some more and I wonder: either you want this to be a value type, because it's so small that copying is fast enough, or you don't. You made it a value type and now you are trying to work around your own decision by somewhat misusing the `ref` and `out` keywords.

```
public static void Add(ref Vector2 a, ref Vector2 b, out Vector2 result)
```

This could easily be

```
public static void Add(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, ref Vector2 result)
```

If you want by-reference passing, why don't you make it a reference type in the first place? If you do, then everything I wrote above would still be valid :)

Comment: The code is being used heavily in physics processing, which speeds up considerably when passing by-ref semantics where possible(note that there are also Vector3/Vector4/larger structs that don't fit in a single machine word). The by-value overloads are there where by-ref passing isn't possible without a copy anyway, such as when passing properties.

Comment: @user3446285 Why did you make it a value-type in the first place then? Is using structs faster at other places in your application?

Comment: One of the main goals of the library is to reduce frequent heap allocations, thereby reducing garbage and subsequently collection cycles. Structs help that immensely.

Comment: @user3613916 indeed :)

Comment: The idea that large things shouldn't be value types stems from the notion that things are often passed by value.  Arrays of large exposed-field value types offer much better cache locality than than arrays of mutable class types, *when one can avoid semantically-needless copying*.